# Reference could not be found on Mac Xamarin Studio

Tags: macos, xamarin, reference, nuget-package

In the MAc xamarin,some referenece solutions are highlited and they can not be found. When I try to add them to the reference, still they can not be added. I do not have this problem on Visual studio and all the references are ok. Is there any trick to solve it?

Comment: perhaps if you provided some specific examples?

Comment: for example, it can not recognize PCLcrypto, and it writes like this: ---the type or namespace name 'PCLCrypto' could not be found. Are you missing an assemble reference. It is in the references of solution but is is dis activated with a red sigh which tells it could not be found.

Comment: did you add it as a nuget package?  What type of project are you trying to add it to?

Comment: Yes I tried, but the "add nuget package" is not activated for that.

Comment: then that sounds like the root problem that you need to solve.  What type of project is it?

Comment: The solution is adding the references manually from the add references.